# Running a celery task outside the django framework

Tags: django, celery

I have a django/celery application that is working fine. In normal operations tasks get created and inserted into the worker queues as expected.

I am trying to create a separate python script that will be run manually, that is attempting to insert a task into the worker queue... and it is not working.

The test function is simple:

```
@shared_task()
def testtask(num=100, tag=0):
    for i in range(num):
        print_log("in testtask {0} {1}".format(i, tag))
        time.sleep(1)
    return
```

From the python3 prompt, I do the following:

```
>>> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "raxakprotect.settings.dev")        
>>> import django                                                                 
>>> django.setup()                                                                
>>> from test import testtask 
# test has other django dependencies hence the django.setup()
>>> testtask(10) # This works fine... but
>>> testtask.delay(10) # hangs indefinitely
```

Don't know why this is the case. Do I have to connect separately to the celery broker somehow?

Watching celery events screen shows no events or entries being created.

Thanks
--prasanna

Answer (score 0):

In the hope that this helps someone else making the same mistake--I found what I was doing wrong. You do need to set up the celery app and point it to its settings thus:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "raxakprotect.settings.prod")    
import django
django.setup()

from raxakprotect.celery import app
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")               
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

The last three lines were missing from my initial attempt.